# Dataflow streaming with WriteToBigQuery as FILE_LOADS mode - draining

Tags: python, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Recently I have been testing Dataflow streaming pipeline (Python) with `WriteToBigQuery` with `FILE_LOADS` mode (batching upload inside of streaming pipeline).
I am analyzing behavior of the dataflow during draining with this set up and results are not so optimistic.
Normally `FILE_LOADS` mode consists of 3 parts:
load job (into intermediate table in BQ)
copy job (copy from intermediate table to target table)
deleting (delete intermediate table).

The most important problem I observed is that if I drain the pipeline, count of load job, copy job and deleting is not in line.
For example I saw that dataflow didn't delete all created temp tables so I have in BQ x temp tables that I have to remove manually.
It does not look like an expected behavior.

Have you observed it too? Or maybe `drain` is not dedicated in streaming pipeline with batch BQ upload?

Comment: I can check if there are any expectations for FILE_LOADS. But in my experience, Streaming Inserts or Storage Write API is used because file loads has some hard limitations of jobs per day, which often makes it hard to fit on most streaming pipelines (1,500 operations per table per day). For more see https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#standard_tables and https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#load_jobs

Comment: Hi @Pav3k, Did the above comment help you?

Comment: @BrunoVolpato Thanks for your anawer. I am aware of those quotas, I think it is not it but I will rerun my test tomorrow to be 100% sure

Comment: Hi @Pav3k, Is your issue resolved?

Comment: Unfortunately no, the issue is still there.

Comment: Hi @Pav3k, It appears that this issue has to be investigated further, so if you have a support plan please create a new [GCP support case](https://cloud.google.com/support/). Otherwise, you can open a new issue on the [Issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers).